# How to update Chromedriver version in PyCharm for selenium-robotframework

Tags: selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, automation-testing

I am using PyCharm to run my robot framework-selenium scripts.
I am facing an issue

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91 Current browser version is 93.0.4577.63 with binary path

Attached are my settings.

How to upgrade chromedriver for Chrome version 93 or any other suggestion. I have 75 automation scripts and it is not feasible to `add driver = chrome path` in all the scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Browser drivers

The `general approach` to install a browser driver is downloading a `right driver`, such as `chromedriver` for Chrome, and placing it into a directory that is in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Drivers for different browsers can be found via Selenium documentation or by using your favorite search engine with a search term like selenium chrome browser driver. New browser driver versions are released to support features in new browsers, fix bug, or otherwise, and you need to keep an eye on them to know when to update drivers you use.

Alternatively, you can use a tool called [WebdriverManager](https://github.com/rasjani/webdrivermanager)which can find the latest version or when required, any version of appropriate webdrivers for you and then download and link/copy it into right location. Tool can run on all major operating systems and supports downloading of Chrome, Firefox, Opera & Edge webdrivers.

Here's an example:

```
pip install webdrivermanager
webdrivermanager firefox chrome --linkpath /usr/local/bin
```

Please go through, [here](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/), everything is documented here.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working...still getting same error.

Comment: No it should not be. How did you try ?

Comment: @Amaze_Rock please see the answer and provide feedback to the poster to try and reach a solution.